# Making Subplots in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Anyone has solution on how to make make the histogram graph a subplot to the ohlc graph, with same y-axis, but different x-axises? Thanks a lot.

```py
volume_profile = px.histogram(df, x='Volume', y='Close', nbins=25, orientation='h')
    
ohlc = go.Figure(data=go.Ohlc(x=df['Time'],
                              open=df['Open'],
                              high=df['High'],
                              low=df['Low'],
                              close=df['Close']))
                           
volume_profile.show()
ohlc.show()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

To create a subplot, use the dedicated settings. See this for [details](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#subplots-types). Subplots are usually enabled in graph_objects, so we have changed it to go. Also, since it is a histogram, it is set to close.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-01-01", end="2021-12-01")

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{'type':'histogram'}, {'type':'ohlc'}]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Histogram(             
              y=df['Close'],
              #y=df[['Close']].values,
              #nbins=25,
              #orientation='h'
              ),
           row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
      go.Ohlc(x=df.index,
      open=df['Open'],
      high=df['High'],
      low=df['Low'],
      close=df['Close']), row=1, col=2
)

fig.update_layout(
  height=600,
  width=800,
  title_text="Side By Side Subplots",
  xaxis2=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False))
   )

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and give it 1+, thanks!